How to use ODBC 64-bit connection for Sybase 12 database in an .NET Framework 4.8 application
I have searched and tried a hundred combinations of answers to this questions, how to resolve this issue:
Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  193:  (SQL Anywhere 12, C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 12\Bin64\dbodbc12.dll)."}
Most issues seems to stem from using a 32-bit ODBC connection from a 64-bit application, in my case this is NOT the issue. I am trying to use a 64-bit ODBC connection from a 64-bit application.
To spice it up, I am running my application on a Windows Parallels on a Mac M2 (Apple Silicon)


You're probably trying to mix arm64 and x86_64 binaries?

Yes, this was true. I tried to set the platform to 64-bit and NOT ARM64, and that worked!
